# vue2 datepicker How do I get the id of the input element where the date was changed?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a table with multiple rows and each row has a datepicker. When a date is changed, how do I know which input element the date was changed for?

@change event only gives me the new value that was selected.

Answer (score 0):

try putting a $event in the arguments of your @change function: https://012.vuejs.org/guide/events.html

it should show up if console the event in the change function, something like

```
console.log(event.target.id)
```

let me know if that works!

Comment: This issue is now resolved. More info at https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/issues/279

Answer (score 0):

Matt is correct but by default Vue automatically inserts the event as a parameter into the event listeners, so no need to pass in the `$event` unless you are expecting some extra parameters into the `@change` event.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    template:'<table> <tr> <td><input type="text" id="1" @change="changed"></td> </tr> <tr> <td><input type="text" id="2" @change="changed" ></td> </tr> </table>',
  methods: {
    changed(event) {
      console.log('ID is:' + event.target.id);
    },
  }
});
```

```css
table, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I think maybe there's a bug 

<DatePicker 
                :id="'date-'+props.row.id"
                v-model="props.row.DueDate"                 
                @change="updateTaskDueDate">

and then in my function

updateTaskDueDate(event) {
      console.log(event);
      console.log(event.target.id);
}

in the console, all i'm seeing is the date that was selected for the first line output and the 2nd line output has an error that says

Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: sorry...it submitted when I pressed enter vs going to the next line..u should see it now...not sure if the formatting is right...i can paste it again...let me know.

Comment: I opened a bug on github as well...formatting there is little better in case that helps...please check here....https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/issues/279

Comment: Since DatePicker is already passing a property, in your `TaskDueDate` you should accept 2 arguments. `TaskDueDate(date, $event) {}`. Make sure you have the `$` before event.

Then you can see the `date` and output the `event.target.id`.

Comment: it looks like the creator of the library decided to send the date as the $event....so $event actually held the value of the date selected...so I have it working now...for anyone else still wondering how I solved it, please check the github page at https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/issues/279